# Singular value decomposition: does the choice of eigenvectors matter?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

I'm trying to calculate the SVD-decomposition of a certain matrix, i.e. $ A = U \Sigma V^T$.

My solution doesn't yield $A$ again; I just can't get the signs correct. I'm wondering if this is just a calculation error, or if I need to choose the eigenvectors in a special way.

Right now, I sorted the singular values, starting with the biggest. This determined the order of the eigenvectors which compose $V$. Whenever I had a choice, I chose the top components to be positive. For the not-yet determined eigenvectors of $U$, I chose the top component first $1$ and than $0$.

I don't think that this should matter but I'm looking for confirmation.

Comment: Without seeing your computations, it's hard to say. The only sure thing is that you *must* get back $A$, if the computations of $U$, $\Sigma$ and $V$ are correct.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, egreg. I did some more checking and found enough sign errors, so I do get back $A$ now. I think the answer to my question is, no it doesn't matter.